# Test if Controls/fields are on the visible tab ms Access

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access, foreach, tabs

I have a MS Access Form with various controls organised into tabs.
There are some text fields among them, and I need the text field to update (that is, the vba to update them) when their tab is opened. The text fields aren't bound, the updating is a bit more customised.

I've tried the below code but it returns `True` for text fields that aren't on the visible tab

```
Private Sub TabCtl2_Change()
Dim Ctl As Control
For Each Ctl In Me.Form.Controls
    If Ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
'Want to do stuff here
    Debug.Print Ctl.Visible 'This is returning 'True' for all text fields 
                            'not just the ones on the active tab.
    Debug.Print Ctl.Name
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

As far as I can see the Tab objects don't have a `Controls` collection or whatever you call it. Can someone help me how to loop through controls on a tab? I don't want to code it all in manually if I can help it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Page` object in the `Pages` collection in the tabcontrol does have a `Controls` property.

This means, if you want to do something for all controls on the active page, you can use the following:

```
For Each control In Me.MyTabcontrol.Pages(Me.MyTabcontrol.Value).Controls
    'Do Stuff
Next
```